# Axis2 Codegen Tool - java.lang.reflect.invocationTargetException

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, wsdl, apache-axis

Im getting `reflect.invocationTargetException` using Eclipse Juno, and tried different Axis2 Codegen Tool versions - 1.6.2, 1.6.3-SNAPSHOT, 1.6.0.

WSDL file which I used can be downloaded here:
http://soap.direct.yandex.ru/wsdl/v4/

Maybe this is something wrong in with this web-service description file format.

Kindly help me with this issue please!

Comment: `InvocationTargetException` is a wrapper exception so that can be anything. What is displayed in the stack trace as the cause of the exception? In fact, can you copy the stack trace in your question?